# about filenames in folder

Tags: c++, filesystems, directory, amazon-ec2

i want to get all filenames in folder in c/c++ .i use dirent.h but it shows error on the dirent.h?
how should i proceed?
Is any way rather than dirent.h?
Thanks in advance

Comment: And the OS/runtime is? http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1046380353&id=1044780608

Comment: You need to tell us what you're running on, what error you're getting and the code you are using. Otherwise we can't help

Comment: Looks like a compilation error, but how can we tell for sure?

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) does this portably. Its [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration) explains how to perform this exact task. In short:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fs::path p(argv[1]);

    if (fs::exists(p) && fs::is_directory(p))
        copy(fs::directory_iterator(p), fs::directory_iterator(),
             ostream_iterator<fs::directory_entry>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

If you do want to use `dirent.h`, include it as:

```
#include <sys/types.h>    /* required before including sys/dirent.h! */
#include <sys/dirent.h>
```